# Transform matrix (in order to draw regression lines using ggplot2)

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I ran a multilevel regression and now have a coefficient matrix consisting of value + standard error for each group (=a factor variable) in the regression, e.g. my matrix (for intercept + one variable called `Beta1`) looks like this:

```
Group    Intercept      Beta1 Intercept.se      Beta1.se
   11  0.044357458  0.4381340   0.08358735     0.1572632
   12 -0.007072542  0.1242737   0.09317142     0.1643544
   21  0.021075871  0.3727055   0.12050036     0.2459456
   22  0.023895981  0.6786013   0.11207848     0.3188887
   31 -0.115713481  0.3547718   0.09760681     0.1454787
   32 -0.004081244 -0.1954594   0.09993201     0.1953406
```

What I would like to achieve is to draw a diagram showing possible regression lines for each group. I came up with the following code which produces 15 lines for each group (`coef.mtx` is the matrix mentioned above):

```
for (i in 1:6) {  # we have 6 groups
  x = coef.mtx[i,]
  lines[(i*6-5):(i*6),] =
    list(Group = replicate(15, x["Group"]),
         int = replicate(15, rnorm(1,x["Intercept"],x["Intercept.se"])),
         slo = replicate(15, rnorm(1, x["Beta1"], x["Beta1.se"])))
}
```

This produces a dataframe like this:

```
      Group         int       slo
1        11  0.09484568 0.3005997
2        11  0.12364749 0.5758899
3        11 -0.02942938 0.4821841
4        11  0.17226587 0.2413752
5        11  0.02923023 0.4251419
6        11  0.14650632 0.4541752
7        12  0.06784996 0.0356669
8        12 -0.02832304 0.2214471
...
```

And then I can draw those lines with ggplot like this:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x=Beta1, y=Outcome)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_wrap(~ Group) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=int, slope=slo), data=lines)
```

The final result looks like this:

[image: Random regression lines]

Is there a better way to transform the coefficient matrix instead of using this loop? I was unable to think of a better way... Alternatively: how would you visualize possible regression lines (and not just the point-estimate)?

Comment: Can you clarify which bits are statistical questions (on-topic here) and which are not? If you do post elsewhere with your programming question you need to say why you want to avoid the for loop.

Comment: @mdewey: The statistical question (for CrossValidated): is there a better way to visualize the range of possible regression lines (regardless of programming or even programming language)?And while at it (question for StackExchange): is there a way to avoid the loop? (there's nothing wrong with the loop per se, I'm just a relative beginner in R so I was wondering if I'm overlooking something obvious, some easy transformation function...)